# google cloud storage permissions - create and delete only

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-cloud-storage, google-authentication, google-cloud-iam

I would like to use a service account and give it storage.objects.create and storage.objects.delete (basically, so when I use this account, I can upload, re-upload, and delete, but NOT list or read a bucket).
I see pre-configured storage roles, e.g. 'Storage Object Creator', which has the create aspect (and works for create, but can't overwrite or delete).
I assume I need to create a Role.  I seemed to be able to do that, but then could not seem to find that 'Custom Role' when trying to add a role to the service account.
So I guess I'm asking 'how do i add a custom role to a service account'?
I was doing all of this through the web ui.
Any help appreciated.
br, Simon

Comment: Are you trying to grant the custom role following [this instructions](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting-console)? You should be able to do that.

Comment: When you create a custom role, if you do not assign an ID, Google does it for you. This typically starts with the string `CustomRole`. In the GUI, click on `Column Display Options`, enable `Name`. Then sort the `Name` column looking for toles that start with `CustomRole`. You can also use `gcloud iam roles list`.

Answer (score 2):

I tested and it works. You can find it in the custom section

[image]